# What "interruptions" can happen when my subscription to Microsoft Office expires?

Tags: microsoft-office, office365

I've had access to a subscription based Microsoft Office suite for a few years, then just about a few months ago the service expired.  Needless to say I don't have the money yet to purchase another subscription or key, but I'm curious about this message that shows up at the top of either Word/Excel/PPT/Access/etc.

[image]

For the past two months I haven't received any sort of "interruption", despite this pop up claiming that something would happen of sorts if I did not reactivate Office.  I would like to know exactly what it means by interruptions, especially moreso since the only "interruption" I could derive was the pop-up at the beginning of launching the program asking me to enter a key to reactivate the subscription.

Comment: If my answer below answers your question, please mark it as such. If it does not, please elaborate so that we can get you a better answer.

Comment: @music2myear I think my issue is that more or less I've had no subscription for about a few months and haven't experienced any of the "interruptions" that they claim would happen.

Comment: There does not seem to be an answer for the timing on this. You could contact Microsoft but I'm rather certain their answer would be "get licensed". The legal and ethical thing to do would be to either get licensed for the products you're using, or to find other products that meet your needs and begin using them instead, removing the products you are not licensed to use.

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search brought this result: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/A-subscription-notice-appears-when-I-open-an-Office-365-application-4cabe32c-f594-4c0e-9191-3d3ade10cceb?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1

Which included this paragraph:

> **What happens if you do nothing**
>
> After your subscription expires, Office will run in reduced functionality mode and will show Unlicensed Product notifications. You’ll still be able to open and print your documents but you won’t be able to edit them or to create new ones. You can reactivate your subscription at any time to get back to full functionality.